# Nginx point subdomain to subfolder

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want http://name.domain.com/ to point to http://www.domain.com/name

Just a notice, **not** to redirect to that location, but just point to it.

So when I navigate to http://name.domain.com, the website display's content from http://www.domain.com/name

What I tried so far:

```
server{
  listen 80;
  server_name name.domain.com;

  rewrite ^/name(.*) http://name.domain.com/$1 permanent;    
}
```

The result is nginx returning **404 not found** error.

**EDIT:**
I want the content of http://www.domain.com/name to be mapped on http://name.domain.com .
So when I navigate to http://name.domain.com I actually retrieve content from http://www.domain.com/name

Comment: Should this only work for http://name.domain.com/, or also for http://anythingelse.domain.com/?

Comment: This should only work for name.domain.com at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need `proxy_pass`.

```
server{
  listen 80;
  server_name blog.domain.com;

  location = / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/blog;
    proxy_set_header Host www.domain.com;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/blog/;
    proxy_set_header Host www.domain.com;
  }
}
```

Here request to `blog.domain.com` goes to `www.domain.com/blog` (w/o trailing slash) and requests to `blog.domain.com/a-title` to `www.domain.com/blog/a-title`.

Comment: I can't understand what do you want to see in browser address bar.

Comment: I want to type http://name.domain.com and see contents from http://www.domain.com/name .

Comment: Yes of course. http://www.domain.com/name gives me output. I just want this to be accessible through subdomain.

Comment: `domain.com` or `www.domain.com`? `/name` or `/name/`? Please, read carefully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54014/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-mallix).

Comment: This worked for me.. simply do / at the end of the Url. Otherwise Django will think you want to go root urls. just because of the slash at the end makes a difference when you setup the subdomain. ;)     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/;  <--- / at the end.
    proxy_set_header Host www.mydomain.com;

Comment: @AdrianoResende sorry? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @AlexeyTen how i set to subfolder, example: admin.domain.com redirect to /admin

Comment: How is it different from original question and answser?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name name.domain.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/name$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: This rewrite is redirecting name.domain.com to www.domain.com/name

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
location / {
    proxy_pass $scheme://domain.com/name;
    proxy_redirect $scheme://domain.com/name/ /;
}
```

It works for me, except I can't figure out how to allow access to the directory only through proxy, and deny for direct access like domain.com/name